# Android : Scrolling in Grid layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

In my `gridlayout` I am trying to add scroll view and I also want my `imagebuttons` at center of screen on both vertical|horizontal orientation. I've tried `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"`
but in horizontal orientation my imagebuttons appears at left.

Here is my Gridlayout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="3"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
tools:context=".Menu">

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/attendance"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/attendance"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc0"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/homework"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/homework"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc1"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/notice"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/notice"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/student_marks"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/student_marks"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc3"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/myclass"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/myclass"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc5"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/logout"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc4"
    android:layout_row="2"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="40dp"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

Horizontal view where my "five" and "six" imagebuttons are not showing beacuse I dont have a scroll view and the imagebuttons are left aligned in this orientation and I want them in center.
[image: view in centre]

My vertical view is in center
[image: horizontal view]

Comment: how do you want them? post a pic if you can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap all your layout inside a "ScrollView" to allow scrolling and inside of a "RelativeLayout" to allow centering the buttons.

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:rowCount="3">

            ... (here the buttons)

        </GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: adding android:layout_gravity="center" in scrollview has done the trick for both orientation.